# Ping multiple IP address using for loop and exec command

Tags: php, for-loop, ping

I wanna run this with multiple IP and check if IPs are alive, unreachable or request time-out. I could not point out where I got mistake. I ran this without using loop and it works fine, but won't work for multiple IPs with for-loop. Help will be appreciated =)

```
for ($ipa=100; $ipa <= 110; $ipa++){

    $ip = "192.168.254.{$ipa}";

    exec ("ping -n 1 -w 1 $ip && exit", $ping_output);

    if(preg_match("/TTL/i", $ping_output[2])) {
      echo "{$ip} is On <br/>";
    } else if("unreachable"){
      echo "{$ip} is unreachable <br/>";
    } else if("Request"){
        echo "{$ip} is Off <br/>";
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you operating multiple ip?

Comment: "but won't work for multiple IPs" elaborate please.

Comment: Why is that done in php? Why don't you use some tool meant for that, like nmap?

Comment: I used loop to check from IPS 192.168.254. **100** until **110** and check each using exec command.

output:
192.168.254.100 is unreachable,
192.168.254.101 is unreachable,
192.168.254.102 is unreachable.

I got it all unreachable results until 192.168.254.110.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at -n switch you are running this on Windows. There are some caveats running exec on Windows but since it worked once I won't go there. The other thing is that you need to unset $ping_output each time so the script uses the most recent data. Otherwise exec will just append data to this array. Finally those else if clauses will always return true.
It will help if you post some output from the var_dump line to see if there was an error running ping with a specific IP.

Here is my suggestion for this script. I have changed the preg_match to stripos which is much faster way to check if a substring is present.

```
for ($ipa=100; $ipa <= 110; $ipa++){
   $ip = "192.168.254.".$ipa;
   $ping_output=array();
   exec ("ping -n 1 -w 1 $ip 2>&1", $ping_output, $return_val);
   echo $ip." -> ".$return_val."<br/>".implode('<br/>',$ping_output).'<br/>';

   if(stripos($ping_output[2],"TTL")!==false) {
     echo $ip." is On <br/>";
   } else if(stripos($ping_output[2],"unreachable")!==false){
     echo $ip." is unreachable <br/>";
   } else if(stripos($ping_output[2],"request")!==false){
     echo $ip." is Off <br/>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rite your ips into a text file and then ping ips by using that file like;

```
for ($ipa=100; $ipa <= 110; $ipa++){

    $ip = "192.168.254.{$ipa}";

    exec ("ping -n 1 -w 1 $ip 2>&1", $ping_output, $return_val);
    var_dump(array($ping_output,  $return_val));
    if(preg_match("/TTL/i", $ping_output[2])) {
      echo "{$ip} is On <br/>";
    } else if("unreachable"){
      echo "{$ip} is unreachable <br/>";
    } else if("Request"){
        echo "{$ip} is Off <br/>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Huseyin, would it be possible if i'll only use for loop? Because it works fine when I tried it individually.

Comment: According to me, it is better using for loop and check status one by one. However, you want to make it batch

Comment: I am not using it for batch file. I am running it on browser.

Comment: I think you missed redirection part 2>&1. I have updated code.

Comment: I got 192.168.254.105 is On until 192.168.254.110, it is all on, but I only have 2 live computers.

Comment: Have you tried my new code? redirection part is missing so anything output to console. So, you are not getting result.

Comment: Yes, I have tried your new codes. The results are all the same from 192.168.254.101 until 192.168.254.110 -all is on. I should have get two On computers since I only have 2 running machines.

Comment: I have added var_dump section in order to see actual result of exec. Could you please try that?

Comment: Wow! The Loop was just repeatedly trying one IP address, it is 192.168.254.100 all over. I wish I could let you see the screenshot of the results.

Comment: http://i1306.photobucket.com/albums/s574/thenorsunian12/Capture_zps3f7c8d91.jpg   this is the link of the result.

Comment: Your requests are timed out. By the way your if conditions are also wrong. Could you please share whole output of script? 100, and 101 is timeout

Comment: Hi Huseyin, here is the list of results    
http://s1306.photobucket.com/user/thenorsunian12/library/Pings

Comment: It is reachable on some machines. Your screenshot only contains till to *.104

Comment: Yeah, It is reachable on some machines, but all of them gave "On" replay though 3 of them are off. Also I have seen that when the exec command executes with loop (*.104 till 105) it always start back to *.100. By the way, I only have 5 machines so I start the loop from *.100 and end to 105.

Comment: Thank you Hüseyin BABAL! You're a great help too.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can mark my question as helpfyl. You're welcome